# Not unique table/alias: in query Java program

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having a problem with mysql in my project.
I think that is something wrong at here

```
rs = bd.consultar(
      "SELECT mensagens.assunto as 'Assunto', mensagens.texto as 'texto', usuarios.username as 'Para', mensagens.data_hora as 'Hora Data' "
       + "FROM mensagens, usuarios"
       + "WHERE mensagens.para = usuarios.idusuarios and mensagens.de = " + Login.getUsuarioAtual().getId() + ";");

        while (rs.next()) {
        mensagemTemp = new Mensagem(rs.getString("Assunto"), rs.getString("texto"),
                Login.getUsuarioAtual().getUsername(), rs.getString("Para"), rs.getDate("Hora Data"));

        enviadas.add(mensagemTemp);
    }
```

here is the Erro:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Not unique table/alias: 'mensagens'
    ...
    at Banco_de_Dados.BancoDeDados.consultar(BancoDeDados.java:29)
        at Banco_de_Dados.BancoMensagem.mensagensEnviadas(BancoMensagem.java:93)
        at GUI.Mensagens.MensagensRecebidas.initComponents(MensagensRecebidas.java:101)
        at GUI.Mensagens.MensagensRecebidas.(MensagensRecebidas.java:27)
        at GUI.Login.jBentrarActionPerformed(Login.java:230)
        at GUI.Login.access$200(Login.java:20)
        at GUI.Login$3.actionPerformed(Login.java:171)
    ...
```

I had done the query with out java code in mysql, i it works.
Some one can see something wrong ???

Sorry about my english

Comment: ow, i just forgot a space after 

    + "FROM mensagens, usuarios "

in query,

Sorry disturb

Comment: Since you've solved your problem on your own, you can either post your solution as an answer (so that other people with the same problem might benefit from your solution), or else just delete your question (if you don't think this solution is likely to benefit other people).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ow, i just forgot a space after + "FROM mensagens, usuarios " in query, Sorry disturb

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.Assunto 
     , m.Texto 
     , u.username Para
     , m.data_hora `Hora Data`
  FROM mensagens m
  JOIN usuarios u
    ON u.idusuarios = m.username 
 WHERE m.de = Login.getUsuarioAtual().getId();
```